# How to access additional referral parameters at receiving end in firebase invites

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

This is sending side.

```
private void onInviteClicked() {

    Map<String, String> referralParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    referralParams.put("Name", "Devesh Agrawal");
    referralParams.put("id", "1000");

    Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_message))
            .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_deep_link)))
            .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_image)))
            .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
            .setAdditionalReferralParameters(referralParams)
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
}
```

This is receiving end:

```
private void processReferralIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Extract referral information from the intent
    String invitationId = AppInviteReferral.getInvitationId(intent);
    String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);

    // Display referral information
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    Log.d(TAG, "Found Referral: " + invitationId + ":" + deepLink);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deep_link_text))
            .setText(getString(R.string.deep_link_fmt, deepLink));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.invitation_id_text))
            .setText(getString(R.string.invitation_id_fmt, invitationId));
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```

I have following queries:

1. What is the use of invitationId at receiving end? is this can be used for any purpose?
2. I am sending map for AdditionalReferralParameters, How to access those values at receiving end?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Did you found out how to fetch the additional referral parameters at receiving end?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up pretty quickly on this idea, and assumed referral parameters have some other use :-(  But I got my data across using deep links:

Found this extra info: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/133
"@droidwala after talking to the team, looks like this method is no longer necessary and will be removed soon"

In sender

```
Uri deepLink = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_uri));
Uri deepLinkPlus = Uri.withAppendedPath(deepLink, family.getUid());
Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(...)
                         .setDeepLink(deepLinkPlus);
```

in AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation callback

```
Uri deepLink = Uri.parse(AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent));
String uid = deepLink.getLastPathSegment();
```

Comment: I've noticed that for the receiver side, if it was sent via SMS, the link that's shown in the SMS is the one shown on the Firebase website, and not the deep link that I've provided. How come? Does Google add the deep link later, based on the new user's phone number?